# Proving convergence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $f$ is a non negative-valued continuous function with domain $[1,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\,dx$ exists, then prove the improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges.

I know that for the first part to have a limit that exists, it must mean that it itself is convergent since it is monotone and bounded by the limit. Not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\,dx$ exists, hence, let $N=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\,dx$, for some real $N$. Also, since $f$ is continuous on the domain $[1,\infty)$,

$$\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\,dx=N$$

In this case, $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges to $N$.

---

**Note** The following definitions of improper integrals of Type 1:

$(a)$ If $\int_{a}^n f(x)\,dx$ exists for every number $n\ge$$a$, then $\int_{a}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^n f(x)\,dx$ provided that this limit exists (as a finite number).

$(b)$ If $\int_{n}^b f(x)\,dx$ exists for every number $n\le$$b$, then $\int_{-\infty}^b f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{n \to -\infty} \int_{n}^b f(x)\,dx$ provided that this limit exists (as a finite number).

The improper integrals $\int_{a}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^b f(x)\,dx$ are called **convergent** if the corresponding limits exist and **divergent** if the limits do not exist.

Comment: does $f$ being continuous on the domain mean that $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)\,dx=N$

Comment: also how would i prove the above equality?

Comment: See the edit above. In your case, since the limit of the integral exists, you can conclude that the integral converges to the limit, and hence, converges.

Comment: is there somewhere you can point me to to find a proof for point $(a)$ provided in your answer, I think I would need to provide a rigorous proof for that statement.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at these: [Improper Integrals](https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_6.6--Improper_Integrals/Improper_Integrals.pdf), [More Improper Integrals](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~park/Fall2011/integration/Improper%20Integral.pdf), [Even More Improper Integrals](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~apotapov/MATH115/improph.pdf), [5.10 Improper Integrals](http://math.ku.edu/~pgu/M121.Stewart.5.10.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^n f = L.$ For $x > 0,$ we have by the nonnegativity of $f$ that

$$\tag 1 \int_1^{F(x)} f \le \int_1^{x} f \le \int_1^{F(x) + 1} f.$$

Here $F$ denotes the floor function. As $x\to \infty,$ both $F(x), F(x) + 1\to \infty$ through integer values. Hence both the left and right side of $(1)$ tend to $L$ as $x \to \infty.$ By the squeeze theorem, the middle term must also $\to L.$ That is the very definition of $\int_1^\infty f = L.$

Answer (score 0):

The **definition** of $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ is $\lim_{A\to \infty} \int_1^A f(x) dx$.

Since for any $A> 0$ there exist an integer $n> A$ and, conversely, for any integer $ n> 0$ there exist a real number $A> n$,  that limit exists if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^n f(x) dx$.